# Can’t create contex for AES encryption. Windows XP

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wincrypt

I have made such code that will create contex for aes encryption (with Win32API support):

```
if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hProvs, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
    {
        if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hProvs, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_NEWKEYSET | CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
        {
            printf("%d\n", GetLastError());
            getchar();
            ExitProcess(0);
        }
    }
```

It works fine on Windows 7 or higher but when I start it on Windows XP, I got no errors, just closed application. And nothing. What’s wrong?

Comment: security on win XP, are you serious?

Comment: @phuclv why not

Comment: you know that win XP has been unsupported for years, do you? And there are tons of vulnerabilities that MS didn't bother to fix, except the two that affects spread too fast to newer versions of Windows because of XP

Comment: even just connecting a win XP machine to the network poses a great threat to other PCs. [Threat of a Windows XP machine connected to a local network via WIFI (today in 2018)](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/185085/89181), [Is it possible to protect my Windows XP users now that Microsoft is no longer releasing security updates?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/59342/89181)

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptacquirecontexta

**Important: This API is deprecated. New and existing software should start using Cryptography Next Generation APIs. Microsoft may remove this API in future releases.**

Comment: It’s not solution of my problem

Comment: @Jureg,  I thought it failed on the new system. I am sorry that I misunderstand the meaning. Did you debug to see where the program exits, is there an error code returned from GetLastError()?

Comment: I tried to get last error but no output. It closes cmd immediately. It’s closing when trying to acquire contex

Comment: @Jureg, I'm sorry I didn't reply to you in time, set breakpoints or system ("pause") to suspend the program, so that you can see in detail how your program works.